# ASP MVC3 - HttpPost action not found after publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

I have an ASP MVC3 application that has several HttpPost ActionResult methods. During a debug session, the methods work fine.  But when I publish and view the web app in the browser only the HttpPost methods fail.  Firebug shows a "404 not found".  Other non-HttpPost methods in the same controller work fine.

UPDATE:

1) The published url for the app is localhost/psp.
2) All the GET actions return URLs of http://localhost/psp/'controller'/'action'.
3) The POST actions are returning URLs of http://localhost/'controller'/'action'.

So this seems to be a routing problem.  The only route I have in my Global.asax.cs file is:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
```

Note that the Home controller does NOT contain any of the HttpPost actions.  All POST methods that fail are in separate controller.  I've tried to adjust this route to: `psp/{controller}/{action}/{id}` but then receive a 403.14 error (FYI I am using IIS 7.5).

I'm baffled by why these HttpPost method work during debug but not in a published app.  Here is one of the methods that get the 404 error after being published:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetAreaSelTexResult(JSON_MapSelPars pars)
    {

        AreaSelTextResult myResult = new AreaSelTextResult();

        using (var ctx = new prismEntities())
        {
            var q = from p in ctx.pPSPMapSummary_Sel(pars.areaType, pars.areaName, null, null,pars.goalCDL) select p;

            // There should only be one record returned, so loop will iterate only once.
            foreach (var k in q)
            {
                //Move procedure results to object
                myResult.TopProjectName1 = k.TopProjectName1;
                myResult.TopProjectName2 = k.TopProjectName2;
                myResult.TopProjectName3 = k.TopProjectName3;

                myResult.TopProjectSnapshotLink1 = k.TopProjectSnapshotLink1;
                myResult.TopProjectSnapshotLink2 = k.TopProjectSnapshotLink2;
                myResult.TopProjectSnapshotLink3 = k.TopProjectSnapshotLink3;

                myResult.TotalProjectAmt = string.Format("{0:C}", k.TotalProjectAmt);
                myResult.TotalProjectCount = k.TotalProjectCount;

            }
        }

        // send object to partial view
        return PartialView("GetAreaSelTexResult", myResult);
    }
```

Here is the Partial View:

```
@model PAA.Models.AreaSelTextResult
<p>@Model.TotalProjectCount projects</p>
<p>@Model.TotalProjectAmt total</p>

<p>
   <a href="@Model.TopProjectSnapshotLink1">@Model.TopProjectName1</a></p>
<p>
   <a href="@Model.TopProjectSnapshotLink2">@Model.TopProjectName2</a></p>
<p>
   <a href="@Model.TopProjectSnapshotLink3">@Model.TopProjectName3</a></p>
```

And here is the javascript that calls the HttpPost method and then loads the returned partial view into a div called "returnedProjData":

```
function retrieveSelectionSummary(selectionName, selectionType) {

    $('#goalList input:checked').each(function () {
        goals += $(this).attr('value') + ",";
    });

    var attr = { areaName: selectionName,
        areaType: selectionType,
                yearCDL: null,
                goalCDL: null,
                statusCDL: status
                };

    var json = JSON.stringify(attr);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/summary/GetAreaSelTexResult',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#returnedProjData').html(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error.");
        }
    });
    return attr;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the View that renders the FORM? What is the URL in your browser, after a POST returns 404? Are you calling this via AJAX?

Comment: I agree, this sounds more like a routing problem than a problem with an action method that is never called.

Comment: @MartinNH - yes it seems to be a routing problem like you suggest.  Please see the update near the top of the post.  URLs of Post actions are missing the application directory.  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Never hardcode urls like this:

```
url: '/summary/GetAreaSelTexResult',
```

Always use url helpers when generating urls:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetAreaSelTexResult", "summary")',
```

The reason your code doesn't work when you deploy it in a virtual directory is because the url  `/summary/GetAreaSelTexResult` is no longer correct. You must take into account the virtual directory name now: `/myappname/summary/GetAreaSelTexResult`. For this reason you should never hardcode your urls but always use url helpers to generate them.

And if this is in a separate javascript file where you cannot use server side helpers you could define a global variable in your view that will point to the correct url or use HTML5 data-* helpers on some DOM element that you are working with.

Comment: @Darin Hi I use a saperate javascript file to do get and post calls, can you please give an example of how to define the variable in view instead of JS file.