# asp.net mvc3 route not found in live environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP MVC3 - HttpPost action not found after publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029714/asp-mvc3-httppost-action-not-found-after-publish)

I have an `asp.net mvc3` application that works perfectly in debug.  However, when I publish the site one of the routes gets a status of "404 Not Found".

The route is part of an `ajax` call and is provided like this

```
url: '../Schedule/GetSched'
```

The Global.asax file has the `MapRoute` like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "CalView2",
     "Schedule/GetSched",
     new { controller = "Schedule", action = "GetCalendar" }
);
```

- Why would it work in debug, but not on a published site?
- What information can I provide to help find an answer?
- Where do I even begin to look for the source of the issue?

Comment: Another reason to test with localhost. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx

Comment: I was wondering how to do that.  I will have to try it out.  Thanks.